# Spring JPA repository delete method doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I can't get Spring JPA to delete bar entity with jpa repository delete method.
Can anyone see where the problem is?

doesn't work:

```java
barRepository.delete(bar.id);
```

Jpa repository:

```java
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Integer>
```

Hibernate entity mappings (only relevant parts):

```java
@Entity(name = "foo")

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity(name = "bar")

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Foo      foo;
```

**EDIT**: git repo with minimal reproducible example.
`HibernateDeleteApplicationTests.java` contains test case.

https://github.com/matijaivanus/hibernate-delete-problem

Comment: WHAT does not work? Any exception? Is "bar" still in the repository? Show us more code around your "delete" call, transaction boundaries may be important.

Comment: @Manuel No exceptions, bar doesn't get deleted from database, that delete method is the only thing that is called.

Comment: first you are using the wrong method (you should pass the entitiy to `delete` or use `deleteById` and pass the id). Second a delete without a transaction isn't going to delete anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not using wrong method (I am using older version, but problem persists with newer versions too).

Comment: The actual issue is your mapping. Your collection is loaded eagerly, which means the `Bar` is already in-memory. Then doing a deleteById is then cancelled due to fact it will be persisted again due to a dirty check. Either make the collection LAZY or properly remove the `Bar` from the collection inside the `Foo` (and set the relation to `null` before doing the delete (or persist the `Foo`)).

Comment: @M.Deinum Indeed, setting FetchType.LAZY on either side of association solves problem. Submit this as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Making the loading lazy still might run into issues, when the objects are already loaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "problem" is your mapping. Your collection is retrieved eagerly. Now why would that be an issue. The `deleteById` in Spring Data JPA first does a `findById` which in your case loads the `Bar` and the `Foo` and eagerly the collection inside `Foo`.

Now the `Bar` is attempted to be deleted but due to it being still attached and referenced by another entity it would be persisted again, hence the delete is cancelled.

To solve you have 3 options

1. Delete using a query and write your own query method for this
2. Properly remove the `Bar` from `Foo`, set the relation to `null` and then persist `Foo` or delete `Bar`.
3. Mark either side of the assocation lazy (this **still** can fail due to 1).

Either of these will work. The first one because it bypasses the JPA caching mechanisms, the second because now the association has been cut. The third **can** work but if the objects have already been loaded run into the same issue as 1.

Answer (score 3):

What if you use

```
barRepository.delete(bar);
```

or

```
barRepository.deleteById(bar.id);
```

I can see that you try to pass `bar.id` as a parameter of `delete` method but it should be entity: `void delete(T entity)`

[EDIT]

It happens because you have bidirectional relationship and you need to update both sides of the relationship if two sides are persisted - attached to the current session

How to fix it?

You can add `@PreRemoved` annotaded method to the `Bar` class to synchronize both sides just before `Bar` is removed:

```
@PreRemove
public void preRemove() {
    this.foo.getBars().clear(); //of course this is just an example and probably you should have more complicated logic here
    this.foo = null;
}
```

Second solution is to create `@Transactional` method to save `Foo` and `Bar` is a separate transaction:

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    @Transactional
    public Foo save() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setTitle("aaa");

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setName("fas");
        bar.setFoo(foo);

        foo.getBars().add(bar);

        return fooRepository.save(foo);
    }
}
```

And now use it to save your entities

```
@BeforeEach
public void before() {      
    this.foo = fooRepository.save(foo);
}
```

Comment: can you show full code how you try to delete it? I would like to see it from the beginning without any cuts

Comment: Using @PreRemove is the cleanest solution IMO. Worked perfectly...this answer should be rated higher.

Answer (score 0):

U can try using: `barRepository.deleteById(bar.id)`